# Loading camera every first time on click of listview item unchecks all the checkboxes from the listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Here is my custom list adapter class where I populate the list items which contain one checkbox and an imageview. On check of the checkbox, an imageview appears on the same row of listview and on click of that imageview, a camera loads. However every first time I load the camera and capture a picture or press back without capturing images, all the checks from the checkboxes disappear, but after the first time everything works normally. Can anyone tell me why this is happening

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;


public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname) {
    super(context, R.layout.merch_items, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;



}

public View getView(final int position,View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.merch_items,null,true);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.merchimageView);
    final TextView merchText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.merchimagetext);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


    imageView.setTag("empty");
    checkBox.setText(itemname[position]);


    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
                imageView.setTag("available");
            }
            else{
                imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView.setTag("empty");
            }

        }

    });

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(imageView.getTag().toString().equals("available")) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

            }

        }
    });




    return rowView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Data change notification to the adapter, recreates your list. In that case, even your second time work perfect does not stand.

The way the `getView` method is written is not entirely correct. Because,  there is no recycling process for the list items, They are getting created entirely all the time.

One way to handle this is to keep a list of booleans where index represent the position and the boolean value represent weather the the box is checked or not and using that value you can set the check-box to be be checked or not!